# How to compute the seasonality in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, trigonometry

I have to computer the seasonality, but my graph gives me the wrong result. The seasonality in this dataset is quarterly (frequency of 4 months)
and with an amplitude of 1.2. I would appreciate and be extremely thankful for any help!

How it should look like:
[image]

My graph:
[image]

```
import numpy as np

x_axis = np.arange(0, 200)
seasonality = np.zeros(len(x_axis))

for i, _ in enumerate(x_axis):
    seasonality[i] = 1.2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x_axis[i] / 4)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
plt.plot(x_axis[0:13], seasonality[0:13])
```

This code was used by the professor so it is correct. But the example he used was different. Maybe it is the period that is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough Xs to have a smooth curve. Use [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) with enough points (`num` should be much greater than the difference between the start and stop).

Also, use vectorial code, not a loop, to compute the points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_axis = np.linspace(0, 12, num=200)
seasonality = 1.2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x_axis / 4)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
plt.plot(x_axis, seasonality)
```

[image]